# ISO/IEC 13818-3 - Does apple iTunes have documentation on standards for audio file's uploaded for streaming and the iTunes store

Tags: itunes, audio, podcasts, mp4

Documentation related to the **ISO/IEC 13818-3** standard. The standard for information technology, generic coding of moving pictures, and associated audio information systems.

I would like to know before coding and modifying audio files such as **.mp4** files submitted to the iTunes store or other media type's such as **Podcasts**, that it applies to Apple's media standards.

- Or is there a universal pre-processing stage Apple implements when such audio files are submitted to iTunes?

So far I have only found a utility set that allows conversion from **.wav** files to **.mp4** by iTunes. Would be nice to know what these conditions these droplet files and scripts provide, specification-wise.

[The Mastering Suite (Apple)](https://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/)

Comment: As you can edit the file before it is uploaded anywhere then iTunes just receives that quality of file...

Comment: @SolarMike So it does it's own pre-processing?